# Wrong direction arrow when popup shows up

Tags: swift, popviewcontroller

I'm using this function to show a popup view to select image from camera roll:

```
func selectImage(sender: UICollectionViewCell){
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum)
    {
        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum
        imagePickerController.allowsEditing = false

            self.popOver = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: imagePickerController)
            self.popOver?.presentPopoverFromRect(sender.frame, inView: self.view, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)

    }
}
```

In the above code, sender.frame refers to the `CollectionViewCell` with the image icon (first one), but as you see, the popup view's arrow is located in the top.

[image]

I've tried `UIPopoverArrowDirection.Down` but the output was wired:
[image]

This is how I call the `selectImage()`:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
//conditions to know if the first cell is selected
   selectImage(collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)!)
}
```

Comment: replace this line by this: `self.popOver?.presentPopoverFromRect(sender.frame, inView: sender.superview, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)`

Comment: @Nishant Post is as the answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more generic way of presenting ANY popover is as shown in the following code snippet:

```
self.popOver?.presentPopoverFromRect(sender.frame, inView: sender.superview, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)
```

Comment: what can I do, if my sender is the second LeftBarButtonItem...?